# Git keeps adding <<<<<<< HEAD to file

Tags: git, laravel, forge

Hi I'm having a real issue with GIT and one particular file. For some reason it keeps adding <<<<<<< HEAD ======= >>>>>>> eb91a364e0e793118b6ae21f19a86acec2fbc159 to the page.

I've tried stashing, reseting (I'm not great with GIT but i've followed a few bits of info I've found and still no joy).

The file in question is fine on my computer if I check the Bitbucket Repo you can't see <<<<<<< HEAD anywhere. I've tried manually replacing the file with the correct one and doing a git stash but each time I push some new code it overwrites that page with the HEAD.

I should say I'm using laravel forge which automatically pulls my pushes. Is there anyway I can stop this?

Thanks

Comment: You have a [merge conflict](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Branching-Basic-Branching-and-Merging#Basic-Merge-Conflicts).

Comment: yeah I knew I'd got that, I just wasn't finding a way to solve it I think it was a previous branch that had messed it up or something like that. Oh well solved now :)

Answer (score 0):

It seems someone working on the same project worked on the same file as you did and there seems a merge conflict. You need to manually check and resolve the conflict making sure that yours and other person's code is intact and not deleted.

Answer (score 0):

I think I've finally figured it out. I actually only use git myself just so if ever I do need someone else to work on it they can.

All I did was run "git status" on the test server I use. Which said I was 22 commits ahead (probably a result of all the messing I was doing on the server with the files, trying to fix it). I then just did a push on the server and a pull locally and it showed me the <<<<< HEAD bits so I could then resolve it.

I wouldn't have asked but I've been trying to figure this out for the past few hours :)

Comment: Do you need any more help?

Comment: No the above fixed it thanks :) I'll mark it as such